# how to bind datasource to the Ajax chart control is asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I want to make a chart using ajax based chart control. I have added the ajax toolkit for it.

I want to create chart as in below link

`http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/BarChart/BarChart.aspx`

By using static data. i can create a chart as below

```
<asp:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server" 
ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth="450" ChartType="StackedColumn"
ChartTitle="United States versus European Widget Production" 
CategoriesAxis="2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012"  
ChartTitleColor="blue" CategoryAxisLineColor="Red" 
ValueAxisLineColor="yellow" BaseLineColor="green" >
<Series>
    <asp:BarChartSeries Name="United States" BarColor="#6C1E83" 
    Data="110, 189, 255, 95, 107, 140" />
    <asp:BarChartSeries Name="Europe" BarColor="#D08AD9" 
    Data="49, 77, 95, 68, 70, 79" />
</Series>
</asp:BarChart>
```

But i dont know how to bind the existing data to the chart control's datasource.
So how to do that?

Comment: Store the Column that contains specific data of united states in a int array , in code behind assign it to barchart1.unitedstates.Data = stat;// int[] stat;

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getData()
    {
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("data source='c:\\northwind.sdf';  mode=Exclusive;");
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select [Statistics] from Products",  conn);
        DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtSource);
        DataRow[] dr = new DataRow[dtSource.Rows.Count];
        dtSource.Rows.CopyTo(dr, 0);
        int[] dblstat= Array.ConvertAll(dr, new Converter<DataRow , int>       (DataRowToint));

    }


    public static int32 DataRowToint(DataRow dr)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(dr["Statistics"].ToString());
```

### }

The above code will give you int array of values , assign it to your bar chart data in codebehind..

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution , just fill data into a datatable , then create a decimal Array like below i did, assign it..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal[] usstat = new decimal[] { 10, 15, 16, 18, 20 };
        decimal[] ukstat = new decimal[] { 14, 18, 6, 11, 32 };


        if (BarChart1.Series[0].Name == "US")
        {
            BarChart1.Series[0].BarColor = "#6C1E83";
            BarChart1.Series[0].Data = usstat;
        }


        if (BarChart1.Series[1].Name == "UK")
        {

            BarChart1.Series[1].BarColor = "#D08AD9";
            BarChart1.Series[1].Data = ukstat;
        }
```

---in .aspx ....

```
    <asp:BarChart ID="BarChart1" runat="server" ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth="450"  ChartType="StackedColumn" ChartTitle="United States versus European Widget Production"  CategoriesAxis="2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012" ChartTitleColor="blue"  CategoryAxisLineColor="Red" ValueAxisLineColor="yellow" BaseLineColor="green" >
<Series>
  <asp:BarChartSeries Name="US"/>
  <asp:BarChartSeries Name="UK"/>
</Series>
```